# Fresh Laravel Install, Artisan Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have freshly installed Laravel as well as a new project, which I am assuming is a new project because the Laravel folder has the vendor folder which contains Artisan.

Now, when I try to run the `$ php artisan list` I get a command not found. Oh and yes I am routing to the correct folder where Laravel is installed.

I am using GitBash to run these commands!

Thank you!

Comment: What does `which php` say? If it does not  find anything, that means that you need to add the php binary to your `PATH`.

Comment: What happens if you do `php artisan -V`?

Comment: I can't run any artisan commands, it just spits out php: command not found... Maybe I do have to add that? How would I do that?

Comment: @Samsquanch still says php: command not found :/

Comment: That's definitely a PHP problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`command not found` means PHP is not installed or PATH variable doesn't have path to `php`. So, it actually not a Laravel problem.

What you need is install PHP (if you didn't do that) and set PATH variable.

Tutorial for Windows:

https://john-dugan.com/add-php-windows-path-variable/

For Linux:

http://www.linuxnix.com/how-to-set-a-php-path-in-linux/

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and come back with an answer! :)

Comment: *Maybe* the best way to learn is to actually do it and learn from there. That's why we have a community like this.